# Outlook 2003 won't authenticate with SMTP before sending

Tags: microsoft-outlook, smtp, authentication

I'm having problems with SMTP authentication in Outlook 2003. My mailserver is set in Outlook, but it won't relay. In other words, Outlook is trying to send mail **before** authenticating.

Authentication and sending work without problems when I use Thunderbird, so the problem is definitely with Outlook.

What's going wrong, and how can I make authentication work?

Comment: Should this go to superuser?

Comment: Ya alex definitely..